# How to autoremove with apt?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, shell, apt

After uninstalling a package I used to do `apt-get autoremove` to remove other unused dependencies.

I understand that `apt` (rather than `apt-get`) is the modern way to manage packages on the command-line - I can uninstall things with `apt remove`. But then how do I do the `autoremove` step? Do I still have to do this with `apt-get`?

I'm using Ubuntu Utopic.

Comment: Where do you understand that "apt is the modern way..." from? The man page simple states that it's a CLI to the package management and to look at apt-get and apt-cache for more low-level command options.

Comment: @ETL it was my understanding that: Back in the day, `apt-get` was considered buggy - it initially didn't handle dependencies properly, so people used `aptitude`. This then took a swing, and `apt-get` was considered the more reliable way to install things, while `aptitude` had bugs in Ubuntu. Apparently `apt` was started when `apt-get` was in version `1.0.0` or something. You're right it basically looks like a neater API for the same features as `apt-get`, `apt-cache` and `dpkg`, but one of the systems guys here at Canonical told me `apt` was now considered the better one to use.

Comment: Funny they would say that. This morning, I randomly did `apt list | head` and got the following warning: `WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet. Use with caution in scripts.`

Comment: @ETL ah well that kinda speaks to its newness doesn't it. Yeah the API of course has to be more stable for use in scripts, but doesn't mean it's not reliable to use on the CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you don't.

Long answer: from the man pages:

> `apt` (Advanced Package Tool) is the command-line tool for handling
>   packages. It provides a commandline interface for the package
>   management of the system. **See also apt-get(8) and apt-cache(8) for
>   more low-level command options.**
>
> `apt-get` is the command-line tool for handling packages, **and may be
>   considered the user's "back-end" to other tools** using the APT
>   library. Several "front-end" interfaces exist, such as aptitude(8),
>   synaptic(8) and wajig(1).

So to `apt` and `apt-get` are two tools which are part of the `APT` library. `apt` can be used to perform some functions and `apt-get` others. They have some overlap. `apt` covers all the common options a basic user would need. `apt-get` contains more low-level functions that a sysadmin would use.

As per the full man page of the `apt` tool, it does not have a command to auto remove unused package. One has to use `apt-get` (or possibly another front-end interface).

Comment: Not directly, but one can pass configuration options via `-o`.